# Eclipse 3.5 with HTML 5

Tags: html, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse 3.5 on Ubuntu 10.10. I am developing a web application with includes HTML 5 tags, but my eclipse is annoying me with the warning messages. Eclipse 3.5 doesn't support HTML 5 tags. How do I update my Eclipse 3.5 to support HTML 5 tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Colorer plugin and use its editor for HTML files.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse plugin *[html5wtp](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/html5wtp)* seems to add the features you are looking for.

Comment: How do I add the jar files to my eclipse project build path?

Comment: Hi cmrn, For html5WTP plugin there is no download link can you suggest any link to download?